# After updating Maven project in Eclipse, running project does not include local changes; have to delete Target folder's contents

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Eclipse version: Juno Service Release 2

I have a Maven project in Eclipse. After making changes locally, I'll run the project, and those changes will be included. However, if I update the project to HEAD and run the project, my local changes will not affect the run. I've discovered that I have to delete the Target folder's contents after every update in order to include my changes in the run.

It is inconvenient to have to delete the Target folder's contents after every update, and sometimes I forget to do so which has lead to confusion and frustration. Why does this happen, and is there a permanent solution?

Comment: How are you running the project? Are you using clean first?

Comment: Is it marked as auto-build?

Comment: Well, the project actually contains JUnit tests, so I'll right click on a test and run it as a JUnit test.

No, I do not clean the project first.

How do I find out if it is marked as auto-build?

Comment: Try right-click on a project and *Refresh* it

Comment: I tried refreshing. No luck.

Comment: Maybe someone commited something to the target folder and it is being replaced on every update to HEAD, thus making your changes go away? Eclipse does not replace class files changed by other programs, see preference `Java->Compiler->Building->Rebuild class files...`